# Expectation values $E(X)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$, given $Y = y$, is distributed geometric($y$) and that the marginal distribution of $Y$ is uniform$(0,1)$.
Determine $E(X)$. 
so this involves the PMF and PDF for the geometric and uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation $E(X)$ is infinite (or if you prefer, doesn't exist). Instead of trying to determine the distribution of $X$, we use the [Law of Total Expectation.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=law+of+total+expectation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr)

The expectation of $X$, given $Y=y$, is $\frac{1}{y}$. Integrate this (multiplied by the density function $1$ of $Y$) from $0$ to $1$. The integral diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$EX = EE[X|Y]$ under suitable conditions on $X$ and $Y$.  In your question,  $E[X | Y] = 1/Y$.

Homework?

Comment: This question was on my test today. I was confused how to go about answering this question.